# eSign with Consent Management in Health Cloud

Tags: experience-cloud, health-cloud, consent-management

We need to set up Consent Management in **Health Cloud** such that a patient can eSign the `Info Authorization Request` via a Patient Experience.

This Trailhead Unit:

- [Consent Management in Health Cloud](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/consent-management-for-health-cloud/set-up-consent-management-for-health-cloud)

It has an image of eSign, giving the impression it's possible.

[image]

But I cannot find any documentation on how an `Info Authorization Request` is sent or presented in Experience Cloud.

**Question**

1. Is eSign or basic agreeing via Experience Cloud a capability for Consent Management in Health Cloud?

If so:

2. Where is the documentation?
3. How do we set it up?